# How to separate a list of features from its shapefile_

Tags: arcpy, shapefile, cursor, fields-attributes, list

I tried to copy all features in a list of dictionaries. The code looks as follows:

```
def iterate_features(self):
    feature_set = arcpy.SearchCursor(self.address)
    for feature in feature_set:
        yield feature

def create_new_dict(self):
    iterator = self.iterate_features()
    if u"Matched_to" not in self.fieldList[:]:
        #arcpy.AddField_management(input_data, u"Matched_to", "TEXT")
        for item in iterator:
            feature = dict()
            for f in self.fieldList:
                feature[f] = item.getValue(f)
            feature[u"Matched_to"]=[]
    else:
        for item in iterator:
            feature = dict()
            for f in self.fieldList:
                feature[f] = item.getValue(f)
        self.new_features_dict.append(feature)
```

Now that I want to fetch the `Matched_to` list, what it returns is a Unicode object instead of a list. Hence I cannot append anything to it. Moreover, the field `Matched_to` is added to the shapefile without being updated or edited. I think it has something to do with shallow and deep copy but I don't know how and where to implement it.

Comment: Can you edit your question and give some background info for why you are copying features in a list of dictionaries?